# Get the message id of a message a bot sent in response

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I don't have any code to share as I am just stumped. I know how to get the message id of the message a user sent; for example, if I did `!test`, I could do `message.id` to get that id.

But I want to get the id of the message a bot replied with, so if I did `!test` and a bot replied with *"working"*, I want to get the id of that *"working"* message. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait for the message to be sent and grab its ID. `send()` returns the message, so the following will work:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  let sentMessage = await message.channel.send('It works');
  console.log(sentMessage.id);
});
```